# Accordions in a Grid pushing content down

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui, grid, accordion

I have a grid of accordions like in the codesandbox below. The problem is when I open one of the accordions, it pushes down all the accordions in the row below, whereas the desired behaviour is to just push down the accordion right below it and the other accordions in the lower row staying in the same place. What needs to be changed in the following code to get this effect?

https://codesandbox.io/s/basicaccordion-demo-material-ui-forked-sw4juk?file=/demo.tsx

[image]

Comment: sorry. I tried to make it. but it seems to be impossible. instead, you can change your component and render items in two separate columns. but you should divide items into two length-equal lists.

Comment: As the main container is a flexbox container, its child elements must be allowed to stretch their height to the tallest element in the row they're in. Like `justify-content: stretch` or `height: 100%`.  Your codesandbox contains a few errors and I don't know MUI, so I can't help you further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize the power of the `Grid` component to get your desired behavior.  Nesting grids within grids is the magic sauce:

[image: Grid Layout]

To do this with the material `Grid` component, the layout will need to be as such:

[image]

[EXAMPLE (I forked your sandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/column-independent-accordions-wtv2xi?file=/demo.tsx)

[image]